# Middleware getting executed multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make a url shortener app using express. I have 2 middle wares for routes `/shorten/:url*` and `/:code` respectively. Somehow when I make requests like `/shorten/iamarshad.com` (requests that are not formatted and will fail my validateUrl method), middleware handling that request gets executed sometimes twice and sometime thrice. Why is this happening ?
Code for route.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var crypto = require("./crypto");

var styles = "<style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond');" +
            "body{background: #fefefe; word-wrap: break-word;}" +
            "p {font-size: 30px;color: #b33c66;font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', monospace;text-align: center;" +
            "margin-top: 40vh;font-weight: 500;word-spacing: 2px;}</style>";

function verifyUrl(req, res, next) {
    console.log("/shorten middleware called");
    req.params.url +=  req.params[0];
    console.log(req.params.url);
    if (validateUrl(req.params.url)) {
        req.db.collection("counter")
        .find({_id: "counter"})
        .toArray(function (err, docs) {
            if (err) console.error("Error occurred while getting COUNTER document:", err);

            req.encodedId = crypto.encode(docs[0].count);

            next();
        });
    }
    else {
        var elem = "<p>Please enter correct and formatted url!</p>";
        res.send(styles + elem);
    }
}


function incrementCounter(req, res, next) {
    // increasing counter
    req.db.collection("counter")
        .update(
            { 
                _id: "counter"
            },
            {
                $inc : {
                    count : 1
                }
            }
        );

    next();
}

function insertUrlDocument(req, res, next) {
    //inserting new url document
    var obj = {original_url: req.params.url, _id: req.encodedId, entry_time: new Date().toUTCString()};
    req.db.collection("urls")
        .insert(obj, function(err, data) {
            if(err) console.error("Error happened while adding new document:", err);
        });
    next();
}

function sendResponse(req, res) {
    var elem = "<p>" + JSON.stringify({'original_url': req.params.url, 'short_url': 'https://shorten-that.herokuapp.com/' + req.encodedId}) + "</p>";
    res.send(styles + elem);
}

function validateUrl(url) {
  var format = /(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[a-z0-9\-]+[.]\w+/;
  return (format.test(url));
}

router.get("/:code", function(req, res) {
    console.log("/:code middleware called with url", req.params.code);
    var code = req.params.code.toString();
    // searching short-url-id
    req.db.collection("urls")
        .find({_id: code})
        .toArray(function(err, docs) {
            if(err) console.error("Error occurred while searching urls:", err);
            console.log(docs);
            if(docs.length > 0)
                res.redirect(docs[0]["original_url"]);
            else {
                var elem = "<p>Oops, wrong url requested!</p>";
                res.send(styles + elem);
            }
        });
});

// better solution needed 
router.get("/shorten/:url*", [verifyUrl, incrementCounter, insertUrlDocument, sendResponse]);

module.exports = router;
```

Code for server.js:

```
var express = require("express")
    , mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient
    , port = process.env.PORT || 8080
    , path = require("path")
    , routes = require("./routes")
    , favicon = require("serve-favicon");  

var app = express();
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public','favicon.png')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/url-shortener';

mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) console.error("Error occurred while connecting to db:", err);

    console.log("successfully connected to db.");

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        req.db = db;
        next();
    });        

    app.use("/", routes);
});

app.listen(port, function() {
   console.log("App running on", port); 
});
```

Comment: Browsers will ask for `favicon.ico` and your `/:code` matches this, you could use the favicon middleware to capture favicon.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-favicon  If you have this middleware before yours it should then capture it before yours.

Comment: @keith I am trying serve-favicon. Why favicon is necessary?

Comment: `Why favicon is necessary`, browsers request this for the icon you see at the top of your browser tabs.

Comment: @keith ok, well. It felt like I asked a stupid question. After adding favicon, some how `/:id` middleware is getting called twice. You can look code and other stuff. at github https://github.com/arshdkhn1/url-shortener-microservice

Comment: That url is returning 404.

Comment: @keith edited url.

Comment: I can't see the favicon middleware in any of your code.  Before your -> `router.get("/:code"...`  you would want something like   `router.use(favicon(pathtosomeicon))`  This would then swallow up the favicon.ico, that your  /:code  is catching.

Comment: @keith I am sorry just updated a min ago. I was working on c9 so I dont have habit of entering password everytime. If you are on c9 , I can share app with you.

Comment: @keith I made a req on `/shorten/iamarshad.com` and got same result twice. dont try heroku, heroku app is not configured.

Comment: @keith I got my error it was a typo `original-url` which should be `original_url`